# use genfromtxt() to load the file and then check the number of missing values in each column using the numpy isnan() function with sum()

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to load this file using genfromtxt and count missing values in each column

[image]

below is my code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt(datafile, delimiter=",", names=["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"], dtype=None, encoding='ascii')

missing_values = np.isnan(data)
```

but it gives me below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-a4d778701252> in <module>
----> 1 missing_values = np.isnan(data)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Look at `data.shape` and `data.dtype`.  It's important to understand what your `genfromtxt` has produced.  With a `dtype=None`, the result is a `structured array`.  That is documented, but it takes time to understand it.  And as the error says, `isnan` cannot work on that kind of dtype.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) works only with `float`; but when you use `names` in [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), you complicate the `dtype`:

> If names is a sequence or a single-string of comma-separated names,
> the names will be used to define the field names in a structured
> dtype. If names is None, the names of the dtype fields will be used,
> if any.

The easiest way is to use `genfromtxt` without column names (as dtype `float`), and then count the `nan` values:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(datafile, delimiter=",", encoding='ascii')
np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data))
```

Comment: thanks.  i tried using above but its taking all the values as null